# How to separate matching substring at first met space char regex

Tags: javascript, python, regex, parsing, regex-negation

I need to match substring in format `!some text!https://test.com/` where anything between two `!` marks is text and after comes url without spaces,

so far I made a regular expression which can find substring
`(!(.*)!((https|http):\/\/[^\s+]))` but it doesn't work as desired when similar pattern is duplicated anywhere in the text.

for example

`!text goes here!https://amazon.com and some other text comes here` should parse

`!text goes here!https://amazon.com`

and it does perfectly, but when I duplicate such pattern anywhere in the text it matches whole text between the two texts.

i.e.
`!text goes here!https://amazon.com some text here !text goes here!https://amazon.com and after some other text` matches whole text

should match two separate `!text goes here!https://amazon.com some` but it will select substring till the end of second match

`!text goes here!https://amazon.com some text here !text goes here!https://amazon.com`

perhaps it takes whole text between first `!` and the last `!`

Is there a approach halt matching when space met after the url text

Comment: `(!(.*?)!((http[s]?)[^.]+.[^ ]+))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!.*!` matches the longest possible substring surrounded by exclamation points; in other words, it goes from the first bang to the last one.

You want to match from the first bang to the next one, which could be a non-greedy match `!.*?!` or the more precise match, `![^!]*!`.

Comment: Great solution, didn't now about greedy match. Thank you!